# Install Kony Fabric in Win64-bit machine

Tags: temenos-quantum

I'm not able to install Kony Fabric in 64bit machine. It throws error during database connection step. 
I have selected MySql 2016 option and when tried to connect error is thrown - 'The driver is not configured for integrated authentication'

Comment: It's been a very long time since I did this setup. Have you gone through this [Kony Documentation](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/konyfabric/kony_fabric_windows_install_guide/Default.htm#kony_fabric_windows_install_guide.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____1)   and followed all pre-requisites?  The better way to handle these kind of setup error is "Create a ticket with Kony"

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to consult with your DBA, because this might be something to do with how MySQL authenticates.  And I just saw that you have already asked this question in Kony forum, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Kony has their own internal Forum site that is very active, and typically questions are asked and answered there. If you are not getting solution here , please check the Kony forum as well!

refer the link : https://basecamp.kony.com/s/question/0D56A00000bfbC3SAI/fabric-installation-error-in-64-bit-machine